# Why does the & operator in TypeScript filter union types but concats object types?

Tags: typescript

I encountered the below code while learning TypeScript and I can't understand why the `&` operator returns only `'apple'` when used with union types but seems to concatenate object types evidenced by it returning a union of `"name" | "age" | "address" | "year"` when getting the keys from the resultant type.

```typescript
type fruits = 'apple' | 'pear' | 'tomato'
type vegetables = 'spinach' | 'cabbage' | 'tomato';

type gardenPlants = fruits & vegetables;

type Employee = { name: string; age: number }
type Company = { name: string, address: string, year: number}

type Info = keyof (Employee & Company);
```

Comment: Because it means "both". Something that's both a fruit and a vegetable must be `"tomato"`. Something that's both an employee and a company must have name, age, address and year properties. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types.

Comment: Read [this article](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you have two types `A` and `B`, then a value of the [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types)  `A & B` must be a value of type `A` *and also* a value of type `B`.  It's an intersection because if you imagine all the values of type `A` and all the values of type `B` as circles in an [Euler diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_diagram) (often called a "Venn diagram" despite being somewhat of a misnomer), then the values of type `A & B` will be those in the intersection where the circles overlap.

This has some interesting consequences in TypeScript, because depending on whether you're thinking of primitives or objects, or object *keys* or *values*, it can seem  backwards to some people.  (This is likely due to [the `keyof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator)  being [contravariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)),  but I digress.)

For [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html) this is fairly straightforward:

```
type Fruits = 'apple' | 'pear' | 'tomato'
type Vegetables = 'spinach' | 'cabbage' | 'tomato';

type GardenPlants = Fruits & Vegetables;
// type GardenPlants = "tomato"
```

Here, your `Fruits` type and `Vegetable` type contain a finite number of specific string literal elements, only one of which is shared in common between them.  The interesection is thus `"tomato"`.

For [object types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#object-types) this might be a bit more confusing.  It's important to note that object types in TypeScript are *open* and *extendible*; a value of a type like `{a: string}` *must* contain a `string`-valued `a` property, but it *may* contain any other property not mentioned.  This is generally useful because otherwise inheritance hierarchies like `interface A { x: string }; interface B extends A { y: number }` would fail to form *type* hierarchies.  Object types are not *closed* or *exact* (see [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) for a feature request to introduce exact types, and the [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) feature which sometimes fools people into thinking object types are exact).

So then, given

```
type Employee = { name: string; age: number }
type Company = { name: string, address: string, year: number }
```

consider the intersection:

```
type CorporationsArePeopleToo = Employee & Company;
```

A value of type `CorporationsArePeopleToo` would have to be *both* an `Employee` *and* a `Company`.  Object types are open, so there's nothing in the language saying that an `Employee` can't have an `address` and a `year`, and nothing saying that a `Company` can't have an `age` .  So if something has all the properties of `Employee` and all the properties of `Company`, it's both an `Employee` and `Company`, and therefore a `CorporationsArePeopleToo`.  You can use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to get the compiler to spell that out for you:

```
type Expanded = { [K in keyof CorporationsArePeopleToo]:
  CorporationsArePeopleToo[K] };
/* type Expanded = {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    address: string;
    year: number;
} */
```

So therefore a `CorporationsArePeopleToo` has all the keys of `Company` and `Employee`:

```
type Info = keyof CorporationsArePeopleToo;
// type Info = "name" | "age" | "address" | "year"
```

If you went through this thinking "hey that's backwards", it's because you're thinking of *properties* instead of *values*.  And `keyof (A & B)` is the same as `(keyof A) | (keyof B)`.  Since `keyof` is contravariant, it turns intersections into unions and vice versa.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgVwJbAM5QLxQOQEMxgA2E2UAPjpLnKRdsAPYC2uj2AsAFCiRQBqEAOYRguAEbF0WbKjBIAdrgDGAC1o4l4sbmHr6zVg2wBuLlx7QA4tQAmEeQAVCueWkyxEKdADJ+QkeKSppwA9CFQFlDWcHaOzq5SUABEjCyMSWbc4NAAokxEDCAQ0FgA3lCKTBAAXFCowHAKgsZQOjUVCExiEHBQAL7m2VAAwsxgLiDu5ZXt9Y3yggA0rTY2cBCoqLVzTctF1LXynd29A5yDvKNwYAxwrEgM8qgAgusOEAxEEAAqDAzueQKRWgvlG+QmwQuuQAHuN5HYbFMoABtADSUAUUAA1hAQAwAGYjW43O7AB5PV4Qd6fYi-BgAXWqXCgROut3ujxebw+XzpaPp-WCIQAVBEhjlYS4EVNmSyKrgqtsGk1gnLWsJDsceqq5bhVutNkr5s1ZSz9nBNV1tVw+lBhSFMpEAJLyfH-LA4vGEq4kjkU7k0n5-IXhZ2u93JGZJcjJNrRihJPVrDaoePJc1JIA)