# Why TypeScript expects intersection types instead of union?

Tags: typescript

I can't get why TypeScript expects intersection types instead of the union in the following example:

```
export type FunctionsList = {
  HI: (arg: { name: string }) => string
  HELLO: (arg: { name2: string }) => string
}

export const FNS: FunctionsList = {
  HI: (arg) => arg.name,
  HELLO: (arg) => arg.name2
}

function t<T extends keyof FunctionsList, R extends Parameters<FunctionsList[T]>[0]>(id: T, payload: R) {
  const fn = FNS[id];

  return fn(payload)
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBiBXAdgYxgSwiwGcAZfY+AXjgG8BYAKAEgAJASQC44AKAQygBzbrThY+AW2DdKUfFkFwAvgEo4VAHxxZ8wUzYBRUqQDy3fkJFjJwAEwyYchcrWbtj3UyVMmoSLDgcIkp0ADkAZW5MXAJg8hCaBhYOcwFBVy00gDpxKQAafVYjU1ShDLhs3LsvH0YAM2w8QiwEAB4AFThQGGAsABNiOABrYEQIOvRG2JJ4mDy4ACUukB7+wYAFARseqGJW6Ka4ihgAbXaAXQ0TgAZLnnw+7nb5sD5EABsIPkfFtSTmIIkeB1Fo0NARE4Pc4AblqzCgwBgGCgLRBPFeHy+fRUXiAA)

As a result, I get the following error:

```
Argument of type '{ name: string; } | { name2: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ name: string; } & { name2: string; }'.
  Type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ name: string; } & { name2: string; }'.
    Property 'name2' is missing in type '{ name: string; }' but required in type '{ name2: string; }'.
```

I can't get why `fn` expect `{ name: string; } & { name2: string; }`.

While my `payload` argument seems right to me `{ name: string; } | { name2: string; }`.

At the same time, using the `t` function looks correct, and all the hints are correct. When I pass "HI" as the first argument, it allows only the object with the key "name" in the second and etc.

I tried to force types, but it didn't work for me. Probably I did it wrong.

How to get the correct types for the `t` function and the `fn` payload? I tried different combinations of types, but it seems my knowledge of TypeScript is not deep enough to fix it.

Comment: This is the same general issue as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75086839/2887218) and the fix is to refactor away from generic conditional types and towards generic indexed accesses into mapped types, like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wE4r2W) shows.  Does that fully address your question or am I missing something?

Comment: `{ name: string; } & { name2: string; }` is not an impossible type; it is equivalent to `{name: string; name2: string}`.  That seems out of scope for the question as asked, though, so maybe you should just [edit] to remove that piece (even if it were impossible you'd have the same problem) and find the answer to that somewhere else (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69945452/2887218) maybe).

Comment: @jcalz I don't believe that answer addresses this. The language is behaving correctly here. A union of two function types, implies directly that the argument types of the resulting function type will be the intersection type of each of the parameter types of the constituent functions of the union and the return type will be the Union of their return types.

Comment: @AluanHaddad It's not conceptually a union of function types, though, it's a generic indexed access.  If you have no expectation of correlation between `id` and `payload`, then [ms/TS#30769](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769) ensures safety by doing what you're talking about. But when you know that `id` and `payload` are correlated, you should be able to do better. ...

Comment: ... It's basically the same as [ms/TS#30581](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) (which wasn't closed as "the language is right"), and the refactor approach is [ms/TS#47109](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  This version is unsound in the face of unions for `K`, but ‍♂️ it's the same unsoundness mentioned in #30769 also.

Comment: @jcalz thank you for correcting my misunderstanding. I missed the correlation when I was looking over the code and the question. I've had a lot of arguments with people who think that the behavior of function union types is wrong because it produces an intersection of the arguments. I think I was lost in reminiscence.

Comment: @jcalz Yes, your first answer fully addressed my problem. Thank you for explaining! Does it make sense to delete the question, since the answer already exists in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75086839/2887218)?

Comment: You don't have to delete it, we can just link it as a duplicate of the other one so that people can still find this question.